# Performance Measure calculation in Python

Tags: python, anaconda, finance

Could you please advise me on how do we calculate annualized standard deviation based on investment returns In python?
as an indicator; I have annualized return, total_profit_loss, cumulative_return, all_trades, avg_trade_profit, avg_trade_loss, avg_profit_loss_trade

A speedy turn around would much be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what specific problem have you hit?

Comment: I havetried this formula however it gives very unusual percentage ASD = (252**(1/2))*(1/(len(capital)-1))*((ending_capital/initial_capital))**2

Comment: What do you mean by "unusual?" Could you provide expected and actual output?

Comment: well, I am trying to calculate the information ratio in order to do that first off, I need to calculate  annualized standard deviation based on investment returns- however, i am always getting very very low deviation on the level of 0.04% and gives high annualized return ( with using the formula of     annualized_return = (ending_capital/initial_capital)**(252/(len(capital)-1)) - 1 ) so that gives very high information ratio which makes unrelaibale numbers in terms of investment measures. would you be able to provide correct calculation of  annualized standard deviation?

Comment: taking into consideration S&P500 dataset and calculation ASD for two years of testing time with 0.04% is too low

Comment: I'm not familiar with this financial stuff, but people might be able to help you better if you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].